# How setInterval works in the background of React Re-Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, setinterval, use-ref

I'm creating a simple countdown timer app with React and I am having hard time understanding how setInterval works while React re-renders the component.
For example, this following code had timer continue to run even though I had used clearInterval onPause().

```
    let startTimer;

    const onStart = () => {
        startTimer = setInterval( ()=>{
            if ( timeRemaining === 0 ) {
              clearInterval(startTimer);
              setIsCounting(false)
              return 
            }
            updateTimer()
          }, 1000)                        
          setIsCounting( (prev) => !prev )
     } // end of onStart

    const onPause = () => {
        setIsCounting( (prev) => !prev )
        clearInterval(startTimer)
    }

    return (
             { props.isCounting ? 
               <button onClick={props.onPause}> Pause </button> 
             : <button onClick={props.onStart}> Start </button> }
    )
```

However, the timer successfully pauses when I simply change

```
let starter;
```

to

```
let startTimer = useRef(null)

const onStart = () => {
        startTimer.current = setInterval( ()=>{
            if ( timeRemaining === 0 ) {
              clearInterval(startTimer);
              setIsCounting(false)
              return 
            }
            updateTimer()
          }, 1000)                        
          setIsCounting( (prev) => !prev )
     } // end of onStart

    const onPause = () => {
        setIsCounting( (prev) => !prev )
        clearInterval(startTimer.current)
    }
```

What's happening to setInterval when React re-renders its component? Why did my timer continue to run when I didn't use useRef()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ref provides what's essentially an *instance variable* over the lifetime of a component. Without that, all that you have inside an asynchronous React function is references to variables as they were *at a certain render*. They're not persistent over different renders, unless explicitly done through the call of a state setter or through the assignment to a ref, or something like that.

Doing

```
let startTimer;

const onStart = () => {
    startTimer = setInterval( ()=>{
```

could only even possibly work if the code that eventually calls `clearInterval` is created *at the same render* that this `setInterval` is created.

If you create a variable local to a given render:

```
let startTimer;
```

and then call a state setter, causing a re-render:

```
setIsCounting( (prev) => !prev )
```

Then, due to the re-render, the whole component's function will run again, resulting in the `let startTimer;` line running again - so it'll have a value of `undefined` then (and not the value to which it was reassigned on the previous render).

So, you need a ref or state to make sure a value persists through multiple renders. No matter the problem, reassigning a variable declared at the top level of a component is almost never the right choice in React.

Comment: During the re-rendering, you mentioned that startTimer gets a new reference. How come setInterval is still running when its assigned variable received a new reference? @CertainPerformance

Comment: A periodic function scheduled with `setInterval` will only ever be stopped if the same timeout ID is passed to `clearInterval`. Other than that, the timeout ID returned by `setInterval` doesn't have to be used at all - if it gets ignored and eventually garbage collected, that will have no effect on the running interval, which will continue to run. The timeout ID returned by `setInterval` isn't a timer object, it's only a number identifier used to clear a timer. If the identifier is no longer accessible, the timer keeps running.